# Why is the SIZE constant only @Native for Integer and Long?

Tags: java, java-8

I understand the use of the [`@Native`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Native.html) annotation.

> Indicates that a field defining a constant value may be referenced
>   from native code. The annotation may be used as a hint by tools that
>   generate native header files to determine whether a header file is
>   required, and if so, what declarations it should contain.

However, while reading the java source code I noticed that in the class `Integer` and `Long` the `SIZE` constant is `@Native` while it is not for the Float, Byte, Double, Short and Character.

Note that the SIZE constant represents the number of bits used to represent the actual value.

```
public static final int SIZE = 8;//Byte
public static final int SIZE = 16;//Character
public static final int SIZE = 16;//Short
public static final int SIZE = 32;//Float
@Native public static final int SIZE = 32;//Integer
@Native public static final int SIZE = 64;//Long
public static final int SIZE = 64;//Double
```

---

**Edit :** I just noticed that this also applies for `MAX_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE` of the same classes.

---

**Edit 2 :** I had spare time to do some research on this, and looking at the header files of the Long, Float etc. classes I had hope to figure out that the constants were not present in the other headers, but unfortunately they are.

```
static const jint SIZE = 8L;//java/lang/Byte.h
static const jint SIZE = 16L;//java/lang/Character.h
static const jint SIZE = 16L;//java/lang/Short.h
static const jint SIZE = 32L;//java/lang/Float.h
static const jint SIZE = 32L;//java/lang/Integer.h
static const jint SIZE = 64L;//java/lang/Double.h
static const jint SIZE = 64L;//java/lang/Long.h
```

---

**Why is the SIZE constant only @Native for Integer and Long ?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TLDR**: Jump to the conclusion

---

> Why is the SIZE constant only @Native for Integer and Long?

### A brief history of `@Native`

I made some search on the mailing lists. I found some interesting things.

**At first** an annotation ([1](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-infra-dev/2011-November/000234.html) [2](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-infra-dev/2011-November/000234.html)) [`javax.tools.annotation.ForceNativeHeader`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk7/langtools/file/5d684df20334/src/share/classes/javax/tools/ForceNativeHeader.java)
was introduced to

> to trigger javah on a class.

It is used by [`com.sun.tools.javac.processing.NativeapiVisitor`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk7/langtools/file/5d684df20334/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/processing/NativeapiVisitor.java). By looking at the code we can see that the native header is generated if the class declare some native methods or if the class is annotated `@ForceNativeHeader`.

**Later** this annotation was renamed to [`GenerateNativeHeader`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk8/langtools/file/27344710eaf1/src/share/classes/javax/tools/annotation/GenerateNativeHeader.java) ([1](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-infra-dev/2012-March/000546.html) [2](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-infra-dev/2012-March/000545.html)).

**Then** [this annotation was added to several types](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eohair/openjdk8/generateHeaders1/webrev/) (especially [Integer](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eohair/openjdk8/generateHeaders1/webrev/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java.udiff.html) and [Long](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eohair/openjdk8/generateHeaders1/webrev/src/share/classes/java/lang/Long.java.udiff.html)) with an interresting comment:

```
/* No native methods here, but the constants are needed in the supporting JNI code */
@GenerateNativeHeader
public final class Long extends Number implements Comparable<Long> {...
```

**But** by adding this annotation it add [a problematic dependency](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8000404) from base module to the module containing javax.tools. So the annotation were removed from [`Integer`](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eerikj/build-infra-m1.1/jdk-base-headers/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java.udiff.html) and [`Long`](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eerikj/build-infra-m1.1/jdk-base-headers/src/share/classes/java/lang/Long.java.udiff.html) and these files were explicitly [added to the build process](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eerikj/build-infra-m1.1/jdk-base-headers/makefiles/CompileJavaClasses.gmk.udiff.html) since the header were no more automatically generated... a ["(hopefully temporary) hack"](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-dev/2012-June/006238.html).

**So** a new annotation `java.lang.annotation.Native` [was created](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/369709a13823) and used in [Integer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/f92ab6dbbff8/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) and [Long](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/f92ab6dbbff8/src/share/classes/java/lang/Long.java). The annotation was set a `TargetType FIELD`.

> the annotation should be directly applied to the constant fields that need to be exported -- and not to the class as a whole.

---

All the purpose of this stuff is:

> javac could generate native headers for classes containing native methods.

It is the case of `Integer` and `Long`

this was a part of the [JEP 139: Enhance javac to Improve Build Speed](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/139):

> javah will be automatically run on any class that contains native methods and the generated C-headers will be put in the (-h) headerdir. A new annotation @ForceNativeHeader is used for classes that have final static primitives that need to be exported to JNI, but no native methods.

---

### A basic experimentation

I made a basic experimentation on the JDK. I clone the open-jdk forest and i successfully build it. As expected the header files where generated for `Integer` and `Long` (thanks to `@Native`) and for `Float` and `Double` (thanks to their native methods) but not for `Byte`, `Short`...

```
    ls -l build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-release/support/headers/java.base/java_lang_*
    ...
    java_lang_Double.h
    java_lang_Float.h
    java_lang_Integer.h
    java_lang_Long.h
    java_lang_Object.h
    java_lang_Package.h
    ...
```

Then i tried to remove the `@Native` from the `Integer` fields and i tried to build again the `jdk` but i get an error:

```
jdk/src/java.base/unix/native/libnio/ch/FileChannelImpl.c:35:10: fatal error: 'java_lang_Integer.h' file not found
#include "java_lang_Integer.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

logically since the header have not been generated.

I have also confirmed that `java_lang_Integer.h` is included **in several c and cpp files**:

```
find .  \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec grep "java_lang_Integer.h" {} \; -print
#include "java_lang_Integer.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/unix/native/libnio/ch/FileChannelImpl.c
#include "java_lang_Integer.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/unix/native/libnio/ch/IOUtil.c
#include "java_lang_Integer.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/windows/native/libnet/TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.c
#include "java_lang_Integer.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/windows/native/libnio/ch/FileChannelImpl.c
#include <java_lang_Integer.h>
./jdk/src/java.desktop/windows/native/libawt/windows/awt_Frame.cpp
```

like `Long`

```
find .  \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec grep "java_lang_Long.h" {} \; -print
#include "java_lang_Long.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/unix/native/libnio/ch/FileDispatcherImpl.c
```

like `Float`

```
find .  \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec grep "java_lang_Float.h" {} \; -print
#include "java_lang_Float.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Float.c
#include "java_lang_Float.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/ObjectInputStream.c
#include "java_lang_Float.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/ObjectOutputStream.c
```

and like `Double`

```
find .  \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec grep "java_lang_Double.h" {} \; -print
#include "java_lang_Double.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Double.c
#include "java_lang_Double.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/ObjectInputStream.c
#include "java_lang_Double.h"
./jdk/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/ObjectOutputStream.c
```

but neither `Short`

```
find .  \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec grep "java_lang_Short.h" {} \; -print
```

nor `Byte`, nor `Character`.

---

## Conclusion

Among all these types, **only** `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double` are used in the **native source code of the jdk**.

And only the `Integer` and `Long` fields are annotated with **`@Native`** because they have **no native methods** (as opposed to `Float` and `Double`)

Answer (score 6):

[gontard got it right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28853754/1594933).

javac will (optionally) generate a native header file if a class contains native methods or fields annotated with @Native.

This was a new feature for javac in JDK 8, and is nothing to do with the Jigsaw module system, as some have conjectured. The JDK build system notes when javac has generated new/different native header files, and uses that to only trigger recompilation of native code when necessary.

Jonathan Gibbons,
Oracle's javac team

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the issue and fix, it looks like this has been done to resolve a handling of a header file generation for special classes in jigsaw

Jigsaw is a module system designated to use in Java SE Platform and JDK. More details [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/)

Here is a corresponding [changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk8/jdk/rev/9fe81cc79176). You can see a comment,

> Special handling of header file generation for classes in the jigsaw
>   base module which currently can't add the annotaion
>   GenerateNativeHeaders. For these specific classes the java file and
>   the class have the same names which enables shortcutting the
>   dependencies.

From the changeset I see that for the sake of purpose in addition to`java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Long` , also some properties in `java.net.SocketOptions`, `sun.nio.ch.IOStatus`, `java.io.FileSystem` have been changed to `@Native`.

So I assume only those were needed to solve the dependency with jigsaw.

Comment: The special handling was _removed_ and replaced by `@Native`.  This doesn't explain why only Integer and Long (but not the other primitive wrappers) are annotated (note the special handling excluded the other wrappers as well).  Still, good idea to check `hg blame`.

Comment: I assume only those classes are needed for jigsaw, so that's why the others are untouched.

Comment: This does not explain why only Long and Integer 's size are native, this only confirm what I've seen. And I also don't think because it is done on jigsaw mean that is was done specially for jigsaw. Would answering "it is done on JDK to resolve dependencies problem" be a good answer to explain why it is done in Jigsaw ?

Comment: The special handling and moving @Native into java.lang.annotation were for Jigsaw, but I bet the use of those fields (autogenerated or not) predates it.

Comment: Are you saying that somehow Java needs to make visible `Long` and `Integer` representation size in bits to native JVM implementations because of JDK modularization project? I can hardly believe that to be the reason...